# Not able to re-run failed tests with Junit5 and Surefire plugin

Tags: maven-3, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to re-run the failed tests using Junit5 and maven-surefire-plugin.

I have tried passing up the `rerunFailingTestsCount` as property and also as config property in pom.xml.

`mvn '-Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2' '-Dtest=com.salesforceiq.engagementapis.TestReRun#testfailure' clean test`

https://maven.apache.org/surefire-archives/surefire-2.18.1/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html

But it seems failed tests are not re-running

This is my simple test class

```
public class TestReRun {
        @Test
        public void testfailure(){
         Assert.assertTrue(false);
       }
 }
```

This is pom.xml

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                    <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                    <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
               </configuration>
               </plugin>
             <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Actual results:

````
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.11 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.salesforceiq.engagementapis.TestEngagementFetchAPIs
[ERROR] testfailure  Time elapsed: 0.176 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.salesforceiq.engagementapis.TestEngagementFetchAPIs.testfailure(TestEngagementFetchAPIs.java:242)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   TestEngagementFetchAPIs.testfailure:242
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.805 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-21T15:40:15-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project siqapiautomation: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/nishkam.agrawal/Documents/projects/siqapiautomation/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException```
````

Answer (score 2):

The feature "re-run" **is supported since of 3.0.0-M4**, see the [Feature Matrix](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/featurematrix.html).

For more details see these Jiras:

[Support @ParameterizedTest for JUnit 5 test reruns](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1711)

[Rerun Failing Tests with JUnit 5](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1584)

[Surefire / Failsafe rerun failed tests functionality fails with JUnit 5 if using @DisplayName](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1701)

Don't use forkCount=0. It is mostly useless in non-trivial projects.

Comment: Regarding the @DisplayName you may want to enable them in fine grained level of configuration, see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#Surefire_Extensions_and_Reports_Configuration_for_.40DisplayName

Answer (score 0):

it's not yet implemented :( 
see https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1558 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1584